# How to check Java version compatibility

Tags: java, antlr, compatibility, batik, documentum

I am  upgrading documentum to 20.2 and java version from 7 to 11 and to do so I am checking the compatibility of third party jars with java 11. How to check if the java based jars are compatible with java 11? batik, antlr etc are the third party jars I am using

Answer (score -1):

So you need to upgrade your jdk 7 to 11 and check for compilation errors. If there are none your problem is 90% sorted.

Although there can be other errors that can occur runtime that you need to check by running your code with all flows and checking if it causes exception or no.